# How to hide components when clicking outside your area

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I have a form with green edit, when the user clicks the search button, the components in red are displayed on the screen. But I want that when the user clicks out of the component area, they disappear. I have no idea how to do this. I saw some people using a layout to cover the whole screen, but wanted to know if there was another way.

[image]

Comment: Use the OnDeactivate event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or use the 
**OnFormclick** event with `object.visible:=false;`